# Finding the largest disk within a convex region using Region primitives

Tags: mathematical-optimization, regions, geometry

[This question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3853102/how-do-i-find-the-radius-of-the-largest-circle-in-an-irregular-convex-polygon-by) asks to find the largest circle within a convex polygon, specifically this one:

```
Graphics[
 {Line[{{0,1}, {0,6}, {4,10}, {8,10}, {11,7}, {11,4}, {7,0}, {1,0}, {0,1}}]}
]
```

[image]

One can optimize over the $(x,y)$ location of its center maximizing its radius $r$, but this seems quite a non-*Mathematica* approach.  Presumably there is a method based on `RegionFunction`s, `Centroid`s, and such to exploit *Mathematica*'s region functionality.

Alas, the natural primitives such as `Centroid` and all the `RegionMeasure`s and `RegionMemberQ` I could think of didn't help.

I have a feeling there is a one-line solution to this, but cannot find it.  It would be especially great to get an *analytic* solution (based on the equations of the polygon edges, say), rather than just some numerical center location and radius.

Comment: I think the answers [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/121987/9490) might be helpful.  I get a good result using `inCircle` from [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/121988/9490).

Comment: Partly related too https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/226058/72682 though the method there was to test random seed points and ovoid other obstacles packing the interior.

Comment: I wouldn't be so certain it will be a one-liner.  Looking at [this site](http://mathcentral.uregina.ca/QQ/database/QQ.09.06/s/joaquim1.html) I'm struck by this sentence: "the solution will contact three edges".  That seems true, but I can't say for sure.  But if it is true - finding the incircle of a triangle is easy and analytic.  Just find the incircle for all sets of three edges, and grab the largest one.

Comment: The solution disk *must* touch at least three edges of the convex polygon.  If the two touched sides are not parallel, one can always displace the disk one of the two candidate directions to enable a larger radius.  In the (rare) case the touched sides are parallel (as in a long rectangle), then one can shift the solution one direction until it touches one of the remaining sides (even though it does not change the solution area).

Comment: @DavidG.Stork Very nice problem. Perhaps there exists a unique "minimal" solution with minimal distance between the centroids of disk and polygon?

Comment: Maybe this answer by Carl Woll helps? https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/164862

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
poly = Polygon @ {{0, 1}, {0, 6}, {4, 10}, {8, 10}, {11, 7}, {11, 4}, 
   {7, 0}, {1,  0}, {0, 1}};

dsk = Disk[{x, y}, r];
```

We can use [`RegionWithin[poly, dsk]`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RegionWithin.html) as the constraint in `ArgMax`:

```
sol = Quiet @ ArgMax[{r, RegionWithin[poly, dsk]}, {x, y, r}]
```

> ```
> {43/8, 39/8, 13/(2 Sqrt[2])}
> ```

```
Graphics[{EdgeForm[Black], FaceForm[Yellow], poly, 
   Red, Circle[Most @ sol, Last @sol], PointSize[Large], Point[Most @ sol]}]
```

[image]

Comment: Great, that's the one-liner ! I tried numerically `NArgMax[{ r, RegionWithin[poly, dsk]}, {x, y, r}]` but MMA doesn't evaluate. Any idea? Thanks.

Comment: @UlrichNeumann, I also tried `NArgMax` and `NMaximize` and had to abort because it was taking too long. I don't know why.

Comment: Mystery MMA... Thanks!

Comment: Yep... that counts as a one-liner! I certainly didn't know about  `RegionWithin`.  Once again the mysterious kglr solves what few others can.  ($\checkmark$)

Comment: @kglr I'm wondering , the code `sol=...` doesn't evaluate anymore in Mathematica v12.2, it only shows `ArgMax[...]` with several conditions like `(Indeterminate | Indeterminate) \[Element] Reals && 
 Indeterminate <= -1` .

Comment: @UlrichNeumann, thank you for catching this. It looks like 12.2.0 updates broke something. I will see if if it can be fixed.

Comment: @kglr Thank you for your assistence!

Comment: @UlrichNeumann, replacing  `RegionWithin[poly, dsk]` with  `RegionWithin[poly, dsk]/. LessEqual[Indeterminate,_]|Element[Indeterminate|_,_]->True`  fixes the issue (not sure how robust this is though).

Comment: @kglr Thank you, some minutes ago I asked for your proposed  substitution!

Comment: You can use `DeleteDuplicates@pts`  to avoid `Indeterminate`.

Answer (score 10):

As an area maximization problem:

```
reg = Polygon[{{0, 1}, {0, 6}, {4, 10}, {8, 10}, {11, 7}, {11, 4}, {7, 0}, {1, 0}, {0, 1}}];
rnf = RegionNearest[RegionBoundary[reg]];
gendisk[{x_, y_}] := Disk[{x, y}, EuclideanDistance[{x, y}, rnf[{x, y}]]]
cost[{x_?NumericQ, y_?NumericQ}] := Area[gendisk[{x, y}]]
{err, sol} = NMaximize[cost[{x, y}], {x, y} \[Element] reg,
  Method -> "RandomSearch"];
Graphics[{FaceForm[None], EdgeForm[Black], reg, Yellow, 
  FaceForm[Yellow], gendisk[Values@sol], Red, Point[Values[sol]]}]
```

[image: disk in convex]

There's a ridge at the centre of the distance transform, so I don't think there is a unique solution but a family of disks with maximal area.

```
ImageAdjust@DistanceTransform@ColorNegate@Graphics[reg]
```

[image: distance transform]

Comment: This is nice, but ultimately equivalent to the general form I considered:  Searching through $(x,y)$ while keep $r$ as large as possible.  (+1)... but I have a feeling a more elegant solution remains to be shown.

Answer (score 7):

In version 13.3, the problem can be solved with [InscribedBall](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/InscribedBall.html)

```
pts = {{0, 1}, {0, 6}, {4, 10}, {8, 10}, {11, 7}, {11, 4}, {7, 0}, {1, 0}, {0, 1}};
Graphics[{Line[pts], Opacity[0.3], InscribedBall@pts}]
```

[image: ![enter image description here]

Comment: Maybe I missed this but I thought the latest MMA version is 13.2.

Answer (score 4):

I played around a bit with this problem and noticed that all numeric functionalities become significantly faster when you use a polygon with machine-precision points. So if you want to use `NMaximize` or the like, I highly recommend this.

Furthermore, here's a numerical implementation that uses `SignedRegionDistance`:

```
Clear[x];
poly = Polygon @ N[{{0, 1}, {0, 6}, {4, 10}, {8, 10}, {11, 7}, {11, 4}, {7, 0}, {1, 0}, {0, 1}}];
sol = With[{
   sgnDist = SignedRegionDistance[poly]
  },
  NMinimize[sgnDist[x], x \[Element] poly]
]
Graphics[
 {
  {Red, Disk[x /. Last[sol], Abs[First @ sol]]},
  {FaceForm[None], EdgeForm[Black], poly}
 }
]
```

> [image]

Comment: I also test `SignedRegionDistance`, your approach is best than  my original method.

Comment: Thanks (+1).  A helpful improvement for larger problems.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork There are some more optimizations you can make, potentially. For `ConvexPolygonQ` polygons, you can use `FindMinimum` using `RegionCentroid` as an initial guess. That should be faster for more complicated polygons.

Answer (score 3):

### Test non-convex set

```
Clear["Global`*"];
pts = {{0, 1}, {0, 6}, {4, 10}, {2, 10}, {11, 7}, {11, 4}, {7, 0}, {1,
     0}};

(* pts = {{0, 1}, {0, 6}, {4, 10}, {2, 10}, {4, 7}, {11, 4}, {7, 0}, {1, 
    0}}; *)
poly = Polygon[pts];
bds = InfiniteLine /@ Partition[pts, 2, 1, 1];
sol = Maximize[{r, 
    Table[RegionDistance[bd, {x, y}] >= r, {bd, bds}], {x, 
      y} ∈ poly}, {r, x, y}] // Simplify
Graphics[{{Opacity[0.2], poly}, Point[{x, y}], Circle[{x, y}, r]} /. 
  Last[sol]]
```

[image]

## Conjecture

We believe that the center of the max circle should be lie in  the line segment.

```
pts = {{0, 1}, {0, 6}, {4, 10}, {8, 10}, {11, 7}, {11, 4}, {7, 0}, {1,
     0}};
poly = Polygon[pts];
fig1 = Graphics[{{LightGreen, poly}, {Red, Point[pts]}, Blue, 
    Text[#, RegionCentroid[RegionDifference[Disk[#, 1.3], poly]]] & /@
      pts}];
p1 = {x, y} /. (Reduce[
       RegionDistance[InfiniteLine[{{0, 6}, {4, 10}}], {x, y}] == 
         RegionDistance[InfiniteLine[{{7, 0}, {11, 4}}], {x, y}] == 
         RegionDistance[InfiniteLine[{{1, 0}, {7, 0}}], {x, y}] && {x,
           y} ∈ poly, Reals] // ToRules) // Simplify;
p2 = {x, y} /. (Reduce[
       RegionDistance[InfiniteLine[{{0, 6}, {4, 10}}], {x, y}] == 
         RegionDistance[InfiniteLine[{{7, 0}, {11, 4}}], {x, y}] == 
         RegionDistance[
          InfiniteLine[{{4, 10}, {8, 10}}], {x, y}] && {x, 
          y} ∈ poly, Reals] // ToRules) // Simplify;
Show[fig1, 
 Graphics[{Text[p1, p1, {1, 1}], 
   Text[p2, p2, {-1, -1}], {Red, Point[{p1, p2}], Line[{p1, p2}]}}]]
```

[image]

```
pts = {{0, 1}, {0, 6}, {4, 10}, {8, 10}, {11, 7}, {11, 4}, {7, 0}, {1,
     0}};
poly = Polygon[pts];
bds = InfiniteLine /@ Partition[pts, 2, 1, 1];
Maximize[{Min[RegionDistance[#, {x, y}] & /@ bds], {x, y} ∈ 
     poly}, {x, y}] // Simplify;
ContourPlot[
 Min[RegionDistance[#, {x, y}] & /@ bds], {x, y} ∈ poly, 
 Contours -> {1, 1.5, 2.5, 3.5, 4, 4.5}, ContourShading -> Automatic, 
 PlotPoints -> 50, MaxRecursion -> 2]
```

[image]

**Edit II**

```
pts = {{0, 1}, {0, 6}, {4, 10}, {8, 10}, {11, 7}, {11, 4}, {7, 0}, {1,
     0}};
poly = Polygon[pts];
bds = InfiniteLine /@ Partition[pts, 2, 1, 1];
Maximize[{Min[RegionDistance[#, {x, y}] & /@ bds], {x, y} ∈ 
    poly}, {x, y}] // Simplify
```

$$\left\{\frac{13}{2 \sqrt{2}},\left\{x\to \frac{1}{4} \left(42-13
   \sqrt{2}\right),y\to 10-\frac{13}{2 \sqrt{2}}\right\}\right\}$$

```
pts = {{0, 1}, {0, 6}, {4, 10}, {8, 10}, {11, 7}, {11, 4}, {7, 0}, {1,
     0}};
poly = Polygon[pts];
bds = InfiniteLine /@ Partition[pts, 2, 1, 1];
sol = Maximize[{r, 
    Sequence @@ 
     Table[EuclideanDistance[RegionNearest[bd, {x, y}], {x, y}] >= 
       r, {bd, bds}], {x, y} ∈ poly}, {r, x, y}] // Simplify
Graphics[{{Opacity[0.1], poly}, Point[{x, y}], Circle[{x, y}, r]} /. 
   Last[sol]] // Timing
```

[image]
$$\left\{\frac{13}{2 \sqrt{2}},\left\{r\to \frac{13}{2 \sqrt{2}},x\to \frac{11}{2},y\to 5\right\}\right\}$$

**Edit I**

```
pts = {{0, 1}, {0, 6}, {4, 10}, {8, 10}, {11, 7}, {11, 4}, {7, 0}, {1,
     0}};
poly = Polygon[pts];
bds = InfiniteLine /@ Partition[pts, 2, 1, 1];
sol = Maximize[{r, 
    Table[RegionDistance[bd, {x, y}] >= r, {bd, bds}], {x, 
      y} ∈ poly}, {r, x, y}] // Simplify
Graphics[{{Opacity[0.2], poly}, Point[{x, y}], Circle[{x, y}, r]} /. 
  Last[sol]]
```

$$\left\{\frac{13}{2 \sqrt{2}},\left\{r\to \frac{13}{2 \sqrt{2}},x\to \frac{43}{8},y\to \frac{39}{8}\right\}\right\}$$

If we add condition to `y` such as `y>=5`,the result is

$$\left\{\frac{13}{2 \sqrt{2}},\left\{r\to \frac{13}{2 \sqrt{2}},x\to \frac{355}{64},y\to \frac{323}{64}\right\}\right\}$$

So It must be exist a line attain the maximum.

Comment: This is great (+1)... far more than was required by my request for a "one-liner."  I knew the solution admitted the circle center being on a line (as can be found by `Skeletonization`) but your approach is analytic, which is almost always superior.  Thanks.