# Placing a disk of maximum size in a region surrounded by random points

Tags: mathematical-optimization, regions

I start with an array of points (`cba`) and add randomness to generate (`cbar`). Four point are deleted from it to generate `x` and a convex hull is generated named `chm`.

---

```
Clear["Global`*"];
SeedRandom[1];

cba = (CoordinateBoundsArray[{{-4, 4}, {-4, 4}}, 1, Center] // 
    Flatten[#, 1] &) ;
cbar = RandomReal[{-0.25, 0.25}] + # & /@ cba;

x = Complement[cbar, RandomChoice[cbar, 4]];
chm = ConvexHullMesh@cbar;

ListPlot[x
 , AspectRatio -> Automatic
 , Frame -> True
 , Axes -> False
 , Epilog -> {FaceForm[Opacity[0.2, Yellow]]
   , EdgeForm[Dashed], chm
   }
 ]
```

---

[image]

---

**Question**

How can I identify the emptiest region and put a maximally sized disk there such that no random points are within this disk. The disk also needs to be within the `ConvexHullMesh` region `chm` rendered in yellow. Thanks for your help.

---

This would be similar to [231328](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/231328/finding-the-largest-disk-within-a-convex-region-using-region-primitives) but here I am lacking the polygon and hence the difficulty.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

- We union the boundary of convex hull `chm` and random points `x` as a single region and use `RegionDistance` to define a distance function.

**Edit**

- Use the approach by @yode in comment.

```
bd = RegionBoundary@chm;
reg = RegionUnion[bd, Point@x];
dist = RegionDistance@reg;
sol = NMaximize[{dist@{u, v}, {u, v} ∈ chm}, {u, v}, 
  Method -> "DifferentialEvolution"]
Graphics[{chm, Red, Point@x, Yellow, 
  Circle[{u, v} /. Last[sol], sol[[1]]]}]
```

> `{1.00713, {u -> -0.694889, v -> 1.49558}}`.

- If we don't union the points and the region boundary, it work for both two `Method`s.

```
NMaximize[{r, RegionDistance[RegionBoundary@chm, {u, v}] >= r, 
    RegionDistance[Point@x, {u, v}] >= r, {u, v} ∈ chm}, {u, 
    v, r}, Method -> #] & /@ {"RandomSearch", "DifferentialEvolution"}
```

[image]

**Original**

- Method -> "RandomSearch" seems find the maximum `r`.

```
bd = RegionBoundary@chm;
reg = RegionUnion[bd, Point@x];
dist = RegionDistance@reg;
sol = NMaximize[{r, dist@{u, v} > r, {u, v} ∈ chm}, {u, v, 
   r}, Method -> "RandomSearch"]
Graphics[{chm, Red, Point@x, Yellow, Circle[{u, v}, r] /. sol[[2]]}]
```

> `{1.00713, {u -> -0.694889, v -> 1.49558, r -> 1.00713}}`.

[image]

Comment: I am getting an [output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oo59W.png) that is different. Could this be version related?

Comment: @Syed  I test the code in 12.2,12.3, 13.3.1,14.0 in Windows 11, all the result  is  `1.00713`, ane the `Method -> "DifferentialEvolution"` give `0.977293`.

Comment: On the cloud, `{0.977293,{u->-0.645305,v->-1.41163,r->0.977293}} ` for both `DifferentialEvolution` and `RandomSearch`. The circle is situated in the other empty space underneath what you have as the solution. It is quite strange.

Comment: @Syed `Maximize[dist@{u,v},{u,v}\[Element]chm]` get same result

Comment: Thanks @yode, it works when `r` is removed.